# ajax html response custom show

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a PHP survey form in which one of the question is "What are your favourite movies?"
For this question, there is a radio button with values "By Title" and "By actor". If user select "By actor", a textbox appears where he can write an actor name (with jQuery auto-complete feature). Then, if click a button "Movies by this actor", a new window appears where he/she will see list of movies by that actor inserted in the textbox. 
Below is the image to explain better:

[image]

### My question:

How can I show this list of movies as selectable links or icons with a small image beside them? (like [amazon search](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_5_7?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=leonardo%20dicaprio&sprefix=leonard%2Caps%2C208&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aleonardo%20dicaprio), that when we write an actor name in the textbox, by clicking "Go" button, it shows list of movies with link and image).

This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="m_scents2" class="field2" style="display:none;">
    <input type="textbox" name= "tag" id="tags" placeholder="Enter an actor/actress name here" />
    <input type="button" value="Movies by this actor" id="btnRight" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var selectedVal;

$(document).ready(function () {
//....
//...
if ($(this).val() == "byActor"){
        $("#m_scents").hide();  
        $("#m_scents2").show();
        $("#tags").focus();
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
                     source: "actorsauto.php",
                     minLength: 2,
                     focus: function( event, ui ){
                        event.preventDefault(); 
                        return false;
                     },
                     select: function (event, ui){ 
                        window.selectedVal = ui.item.value;
                     }
                  });  
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>

$('#btnRight').on('click', function (e) {
           popupCenter("movieByactor.php","_blank","400","400");
  });
```

and here is a child code(movieByactor.php):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id= "field"
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var selectedVal = parent.window.opener.selectedVal; 

 $.ajax({
         url: 'childfilm.php',  //THIS IS A PHP FILE CONTAIN QUERY TO SELECT MOVIES BY THE INSERTED ACTOR IN THE TEXTBOX
         datatype: "json",
         data:{q:selectedVal},
         success: function(response) {     
                     $("#field").html(response);
                   }
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### UPDATE_1:

this is childfilm.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q'])){
try{ 

    include('imdbConnection.php');
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT movieName FROM cast_movie WHERE castName = :q");
    $sql->execute(array(':q' => $_GET['q']));

    while($rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $option = '<option value="' . $rows['movieName'] . '">' . $rows['movieName'] . '</option>';
       $html .= $option;
       }

    } catch(PDOException $e){
           echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
       }
   echo $html; 
   exit;
```

Comment: Are you looking for jQuey autoComplete?

Comment: @voidmain: NO! actually I could integrate a small image in auto-complete results... but this is not what I want.. Please kindly see the amazon link in my question, you may get better idea of what I am looking for.

Comment: You need to change the output in childfilm.php to create the links. When you receive them via AJAX and place them in `#field` they will be rendered as links. Post the code for childfilm.php here.

Comment: @voidmain: I don't have ay auto-completion in child window! I just want to show the list of movies with their image (Like amazon)

Comment: what jquery plugin you are using? i have done it using _jquery ui autocomplete_ and _select 2_

Comment: The output in childfilm.php shouldn't be an option list, should it?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: No actually at the beginning I showed them in dropdown, then my supervisor asked me not to show them in dropdown, instead I have to show them exactly like what amazon does... --> http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_5_7?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=leonardo%20dicaprio&sprefix=leonard%2Caps%2C208&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aleonardo%20dicaprio

Comment: All you need to do is make changes to the `$option` output, making those links instead of select options.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: this is what I really don't know.. :(

Comment: you don't know how to modify the simple html output from an option tag to an `<a>` tag?

Comment: @charlietfl: No , I really didnt know this SIMPLE thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need changes to your output to suit your situation. For instance, changing this line -

```
$option = '<option value="' . $rows['movieName'] . '">' . $rows['movieName'] . '</option>';
```

to something like -

```
$option = '<a href=movie.php?title="' . $rows['movieName'] . '">' . $rows['movieName'] . '</a><br />';
```

will output a link to a page called movie.php which references the title of the movie in the query string, for example -

```
http://www.example.com/movie.php?title=Big
```

You can add pictures, icons or any markup that you desire for each of the returned items.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. Just one more question: how can I insert a line break between each movie? because now they are all shown in one link!

Comment: I made an edit - just a add a line break after the closing `</a><br />` tag as shown.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Blanchard, that's a French family name. Y'all from the 'ol Cajun country, or from The Maritimes?

Comment: A little of both @Fred-ii-, family started in The Maritimes (N.S. specifically) and wandered down coast with others and mixed with some from the U.S. Midwest. Still speak a little French and getting better with practice speaking to older relatives and friends.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I was up in The Maritimes quite a few times and noticed a lot of Blanchards, so I know the family name quite well. Je parle le français aussi mon cher ami ;) très bien en fait (*surprised huh?*). Nova Scotia's a real gem, loved every part of it. The folk there are great, so is the food, music, the coast. Going back there next year actually. (*I'll say hi for ya*)

Comment: Pas surpris du tout! Although I do get a lot of the Cajun dialect mixed in. Grew up with grandparents and aunts and uncles speaking it all of the time. I love N.S. and hope to go next year as well. and Blanchard == Smith in the U.S.

Comment: LOL! Yeah, I believe it: Blanchard == Smith hahaha! Yep, they are widespread throughout N.S. and not just there neither, but New Brunswick as well. Dat where dah cajun live too ye know ;) J'adore le gumbo aussi ;) Grandparents have the best (if one can say) recipes for "la bonne cuisine". Blackened gator, jumbalaya... yeah, I know all about dat stuff.

Comment: Laissez les bons tons (*temps*) rouler! ♫

Comment: Rouler avec les bons tons!

Comment: I just had a look at your Twitter profile. I didn't even know y'all livin' in Cajun Country before I wrote that above, *honest*. You and I are brothers from another life, really hehehe. Musician, photog, builder of thangs. Dude, y'all a spittin' image lol - Minus the Dad part though lol! *Goatie 'n all* - I've a few friends living up there actually.

Comment: That is too cool @Fred-ii-, I *knew* we were cut from the same cloth!

Comment: As did I Jay :) wouldn't doubt it if we had some distant family relation.

Comment: Shot you an e-mail ....I think....@Fred-ii- as all of this would likely be better discussed in e-mail :)

Comment: I don't think it made it. I hope you've saved it in your "Sent" section. I'll fire one off to you, you'll know it's me.